# How do I get a file from another volume using docker compose.yml file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Suppose, I have two apps: A and B. A's files are in a folder named: step1, and B's files are in a folder named: step2. Both A and B have their own Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml. I allocate two different volumes for A and B. But B needs a file from A's volume. So what should be done to do this? How should I do this using docker-compose.yml?

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  step1:
    build: ./step1/
    command: uvicorn app:app --host 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - myapp:/app
    ports:
      - 8008:8000
  step3:
    build: ./step3/
    command: uvicorn app:app --host 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - myapp:/app
    ports:
      - 8009:8000


volumes:
  myapp:
```

Comment: A best practice would be for one container to send the other the file using an HTTP POST, or via a message-queueing system.  Sharing files introduces some complexities and doesn't scale to larger container systems like Kubernetes.

Comment: share your attempt! share your docker-compose file(s)! After pasting your code, select it and format it with Ctrl+k or Cmd+K

Comment: shared. plz check now. @AbdennourTOUMI